# OpenGL ES 2.0 fragment shader arithmetic incorrect on iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader

I am very new to GLSL so please excuse the basic nature of these questions..

First of all, a call to:

```
int range[2], precision;
glGetShaderPrecisionFormat(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, GL_HIGH_FLOAT, range, &precision);
```

For my device this returns `precision = 23`, and `range = {127, 127}`. Before I go any further, my understanding of this is that this is therefore a 32-bit float (1 sign + 8 exp + 23 mantissa)- is this correct?

Second, my goal is to emulate double-float precision in a fragment shader using [this method](http://andrewthall.org/papers/df64_qf128.pdf). I split a double into 2 floats on the CPU side using the following code:

```
static double const SPLITTER = (1 << 29) + 1;

static inline void set2d(double a, float* b, float* c) {
    double t = a * SPLITTER;
    double hi = t - (t - a);
    double lo = a - hi;
    *b = (float)hi;
    *c = (float)lo;
}
```

Then I set 2 uniforms in the fragment shader with the returned hi/lo values. The uniforms are declared like this:

```
precision highp float;
uniform float u_h0, u_h1;
```

The problem I have is that in the following code:

```
float a = u_h0;
float b = u_h1;
float s=a+b;
float e=b-(s-a);  // always 0
```

The overflow term `float e=b-(s-a);` always evaluates to 0 on the GPU (I debugged by setting colours based on value), no matter what I pass in for `u_h0` and `u_h1` (I also confirmed that both these were non-zero).

It seems like the compiler may be interpreting `e` as `b - ((a + b) - a) == (b - b) == 0`, ie optimising code away at compile time.

Does this seem likely, and if so how could I stop this from happening?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing:

```
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
```

To:

```
invariant varying vec2 v_texCoords;
```

In both vertex and fragment shaders fixes the problem.